# Reduce size of function

Tags: php, mysql

I've created this function below but i'm sure i'm doing it inefficiently ( less code ).
Is there a better way to do it?

```
function Select_Workorder_Type($Selected = NULL){
    $q = DB::query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_workorders_type`");
    $v = '<select id="Workorder_Type" name="Workorder_Type" class="Formfield_Select" required>';
    foreach ($q as $r) {
        if ($r['Workorders_Type_ID'] == $Selected) {
            $s = 'selected="selected"';
        }
        $v .= '<option '.$s.' value="'.$r['Workorders_Type_ID'].'" >'  . $r['Workorders_Type_Name'] . '</option>';
        unset($s);
    }
    $v .= '</select>';
    echo $v;
}
```

Comment: this is best. did you faced any problem with it?

Comment: 1. You should convert all applicable characters to HTML entities with `htmlentities`
2. Static methods `DB::query` are not good for unit tests

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for peer review of working code. As such, it is better suited for [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: Yes its working perfectly, but as i'm trying to improve my skills i thought i would ask here. Ken i did not know of code review i will close this and ask it there

Comment: @KenWhite I think it's not a significant enough body of code for CR.